# How to allow cross-domain file uploads?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have an html5 uploader thanks to the following tutorial:
http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/ajax-file-upload-xmlhttprequest-level-2/
works great.. however I would like to upload the files to a different domain... I thought this would be possible as long as the domain, or more specifically the file on the domain I was uploading too had the follwong header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
```

Therefore allowing cross domain sharing...
However the upload is not working, is there anything else I am missing, or is it a case that you can communicate across domains but you can't upload files?
Kind regards to any responders...

J

Comment: Define "not working". What errors do you get? What code are you trying to use?

Comment: I thought "not working" was a technical term :)... The upload is not getting processed and I am getting the following error [object XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent]... I have editted the question with a link to the code I am using.. J

Comment: What does the HTTP request look like? What gets received on the server? Is something received but corrupt? Don't show us a tutorial you are following, that won't pick up transcription errors, show us real code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option for cross domain upload is to use ftp upload (of course you need to know ftp access credential such as ftp host, username and password.

If your using php as server side language you can try this little piece of code.

I use this on multiple domains within the same web server.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($server) or die("<span style='color:#FF0000'>Can't connect to ".$server."</span>");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password) or die();
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $server_path, $file, FTP_BINARY);
if (!$upload) {
    echo "Error sending image to ".$server;
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Pluda for the response, but that isn't really what I am trying to do... kind regrards J